# Find the number of solutions in positive integers for the inequality $0 < x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} \leq 6$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I can solve for this case $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} \leq 6$.But with the zero I don't know.What changes?

Comment: The $x_i$ are positive integers, so of course their sum is positive. The condition $0<x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ is obviously satisfied. The other condition is the one you must take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_i \geq 0$ for $i=1..6$. Since the only way to get zero is $x_1 = ...=x_4=0$, if you obtained $N$ solutions when you solved the case $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} \leq 6$, the number of solutions for the case $0<x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} \leq 6$ is $N-1$.

If $x_i > 0$ for $i=1..6$. Nothing changes, you still have $N$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You want one fewer than the number of ways to get the non-negative sum $6 = a+b+c+d+e$ where $e$ is added to the sum of the $x$'s to make a total of $6$. "One fewer" is to discount the $e=6$ sum.

This is the same the number of ways to write $6+5 = 11 = A+B+C+D+E$ as a sum of $5$ positive numbers by adding $1$ to each summand.

This the same as the number of ways to place $4$ bars in $4$ distinct gaps chosen from the $10$ gaps between adjacent stars in a row of $11$ stars.

So you get $C(10,4)-1 = 209$